# Do male humans have a mons pubis?

Tags: human-anatomy, anatomy

Wikipedia [writes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mons_pubis):

> In human anatomy, and in mammals in general, the mons pubis (also known simply as the mons, and known specifically in females as the mons Venus or mons veneris), is a rounded mass of fatty tissue found over the pubic symphysis of the pubic bones. In human females, the mons pubis forms the anterior portion of the vulva. It divides into the labia majora (literally "larger lips"), on either side of the furrow known as the pudendal cleft, that surrounds the labia minora, clitoris, urethra, vaginal opening, and other structures of the vulval vestibule.

The Foundational Model of Anatomy [suggests](http://xiphoid.biostr.washington.edu/fma/fmabrowser-hierarchy.html?search=Pelvis&entryPoint=none&extendHierarchy=false) that the feature also exist in the non-gender specific pelvis concept. Does it?

Answer (score 1):

Technically men do have a mons pubis but it is less pronounced. With increased estrogen in females it becomes more pronounced.

[Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mons_pubis)

Comment: Please add some references to your answer.

Comment: pronounced = expressed?